# Rx how to merge observables and only fire if all provided an onnext in a specified timeframe

Tags: system.reactive, rxjs, observable

I have a number of observable event streams that are all providing events with timestamps. I don't care about the events individually, I need to know when they all fired within a specified timeframe.

For example: 
Button one was clicked (don't care)
Button two was clicked (don't care)
Button one was clicked and within 5 seconds button two was clicked (I need this)

I tried "and then when" but I get old events and can't figure out how to filter them out if it is not within the time window.

Thanks!

Edit:
I attempted to create a marble diagram to clarify what I am trying to achieve...

I have a bunch of random event streams represented in the top portion. Some events fire more often then others. I only want to capture the group of events that fired within a specified time window. In this example I used windows of 3 seconds. The events I want are highlighted in dark black all other events should be ignored. I hope this helps better explain the problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a marble diagram showing what you expect?

Comment: @Shlomo, I updated the description. Thanks

Comment: So the last event in each window should be passed on, while the others in the window ignored?

Comment: Correct, that is what I want to accomplish. I can't seem to get the grouped events and sample to work correctly. JS or c# code examples work for examples

Comment: Provided .NET sample.

Comment: Your marble diagram suggests that your interval is regular (i.e. every three seconds). Is this this the case? i.e. is the sampling interval fixed, or do you want "whenever all of these things happen within n seconds of each other, from first occurrence to last"?

Comment: Ideally I would like to have a sliding window. If All the events happen withing 3 seconds I would like to know. I could probably make it work with fixed windows but I would be missing some events.

Answer (score 0):

Is sequence important? If so, the usual way of dealing with "this and then that" is using flatMapLatest. You can achieve your other constraints by applying them to stream passed to flatMapLatest. Consider the following example:

```
const fromClick = x => Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById(x), 'click');

const a$ = fromClick('button1');
const b$ = fromClick('button2');

const sub = a$.flatMapLatest(() => b$.first().timeout(5000, Rx.Observable.never()))
              .subscribe(() => console.log('condition met'));
```

Here we're saying "for each click on button 1, start listening to button 2, and return either the first click or nothing (if we hit the timeout). Here's a working example: https://jsbin.com/zosipociti/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Thanks Matt, sequence doesn't matter, in fact I need to be able to detect of the events happen in any order. I may also have significantly more event streams involved.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [Sample operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html). I'm not sure if you want .NET or JS sample code, since you tagged both.

---

**Edit:**

Here's a .NET sample. `metaSample` is an observable of 10 child observables. Each of the child observables has numbers going from 1 to 99 with random time-gaps between each number. The time gaps are anywhere between 0 to 200 milliseconds.

```
var random = new Random();

IObservable<IObservable<int>> metaSample = Observable.Generate(1, i => i < 10, i => i + 1, i => 
    Observable.Generate(1, j => j < 100, j => j + 1, j => j, j => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(200))));
```

We then Sample each of the child operators every one second. This gives us the latest value that occurred in that one second window. We then merge those sampled streams together:

```
IObservable<int> joined = metaSample
    .Select(o => o.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
    .Merge();
```

A marble diagram for 5 of them could look like this:

```
child1: --1----2--3-4---5----6
child2: -1-23---4--5----6-7--8
child3: --1----2----3-4-5--6--
child4: ----1-2--34---567--8-9
child5: 1----2--3-4-5--------6-
t     : ------1------2------3-
------------------------------
result: ------13122--45345--5768--
```

So the after 1 second, it grabs the latest from each child and dumps it, after 2 seconds the same. After 3 seconds, notice that child5 hasn't emitted anything, so there's only 4 numbers emitted. Obviously with our parameters that's impossible, but that's demonstrated as how `Sample` would work with no events.

Comment: I found this great discussion regarding these concepts in Rx. https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Programming-Streams-of-Coincidence-with-Join-and-GroupJoin-for-Rx

I have watched it and the example that they discuss (who is in the room at the same time) is very similar... Except I only want an event when everyone is in the room. In your provided example I want an event when all the observables fired in the given window. Maybe it isn't possible and I need to inspect every event for the inclusion of all events. They discuss this, it seems that a combo of window or groupjoin may work.

Comment: I think I understand now. So for the above marble diagram, the events at t1 and t2 are fine, but there should be nothing emitted at t3?

Comment: disregard this comment

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I have come to accomplishing this task... There has to be a cleaner way with groupjoin but I can't figure it out!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var o1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Select(t => "A " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        o1.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        var o2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Select(t => "B " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        o2.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        var o3 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(3, 7))).Select(t => "C " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        o3.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        var o4 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(5, 10))).Select(t => "D " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        o4.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        var joined = o1
            .CombineLatest(o2, (s1, s2)=> new { e1 = s1, e2 = s2})
            .CombineLatest(o3, (s1, s2) => new { e1 = s1.e1, e2 = s1.e2, e3 = s2 })
            .CombineLatest(o4, (s1, s2) => new { e1 = s1.e1, e2 = s1.e2, e3 = s1.e3, e4 = s2 })
            .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        joined.Subscribe(e => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: {e.e1} - {e.e2} - {e.e3} - {e.e4}"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```